# Parse Cloud: Query not running in exported function from save() callback

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm using Parse to represent the state of a beer keg (among other things). I'd like to check the user's notifications, stored in a "Notifications" table, to see if they'd like to receive a notification when the keg is filled.

I have all of the logic for setting the user's notification settings as well as sending notifications in cloud/notifications.js. All of the logic for updating the keg is in cloud/beer.js. I created an exported function called "sendKegRefillNotification" which performs a query.find() on the Notifications table and gets called from beer.js.

The problem is that it doesn't seem to be executing query.find() when I call the function from beer.js, however when I call the same function from a job within notifications.js, it works just fine.

main.js:

```
require("cloud/beer.js");
require("cloud/notifications.js");
```

beer.js:

```
var notify = require("cloud/notifications.js");

var Keg = Parse.Object.extend("Keg");

var fillKeg = function(beerName) {
    var promise = new Parse.Promise();

    var keg = new Keg();
    keg.set("beerName", beerName)
    keg.set("kickedReports", []);
    keg.save(null, { useMasterKey: true }).then(function(keg) {
        console.log("Keg updated to " + beerName + ".");
        promise.resolve(keg);
        notify.sendKegRefillNotification(keg);
    },
    function(keg, error) {
        promise.reject(error);
    });

    return promise;
}

Parse.Cloud.define("beerFillKeg", function(request, response) {
    var beerName = request.params.name;
    if (!beerName) {
        response.error("No beer was specified.");
        return;
    }
    if (!util.isUserAdmin(request.user)) {
        response.error("User does not have permission to update the keg.");
        return;
    }
    fillKeg(beerName).then(function(keg) {
        kegResponse(keg).then(function(result) {
            response.success(result);
        });
    },
    function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});

function kegResponse(keg) {
    var promise = new Parse.Promise();

    var result = {
        id: keg.id,
        beer: {
            name: keg.get("beerName")
        },
        filled: keg.createdAt,
        kickedReports: []
    };

    var kickedReports = keg.get("kickedReports");
    if (!kickedReports || kickedReports.length == 0) {
        promise.resolve(result);
    } else {
        util.findUsers(kickedReports).then(function(users) {
            result.kickedReports = util.infoForUsers(users);
            promise.resolve(result);
        }, function(users, error) {
            console.log(error);
            promise.resolve(result);
        });
    }
    return promise;
}
```

notifications.js:

```
var Keg = Parse.Object.extend("Keg");
var Notification = Parse.Object.extend("Notifications");

exports.sendKegRefillNotification = function(keg) {
    var beerName = keg.get("beerName");
    console.log("Sending notifications that keg is refilled to '" + beerName + "'.");

    var promise = new Parse.Promise();

    var query = new Parse.Query(Notification);
    query.include("user");
    query.equalTo("keg_filled", true);
    query.find({ useMasterKey: true }).then(function(notifications) {
        console.log("Found notifications!");
        promise.resolve("Found notifications!");
    },
    function(notifications, error) {
        console.error("No notifications");
        console.error(error);
        promise.reject(error);
    });

    return promise;
}

Parse.Cloud.job("beerSendRefillNotification", function(request, status) {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Keg);
    query.descending("createdAt");
    query.first().then(function(keg) {
        if (!keg) {
            status.error("No keg");
            return;
        }

        exports.sendKegRefillNotification(keg);
    },
    function(keg, error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

When I run the job "beerSendRefillNotification" from the Parse dashboard, I can tell that query.find() is getting called because it prints "Found notifications!":

```
E2015-02-23T06:59:49.006Z]v1564 Ran job beerSendRefillNotification with:
  Input: {}
  Result: success/error was not called
I2015-02-23T06:59:49.055Z]false
I2015-02-23T06:59:49.190Z]Sending notifications that keg is refilled to 'test'.
I2015-02-23T06:59:49.243Z]Found notifications!
```

However, when I call the cloud function "beerFillKeg", it isn't because it's not printing "Found notifications!" or "No notifications":

```
I2015-02-23T07:00:17.414Z]v1564 Ran cloud function beerFillKeg for user HKePOEWZvC with:
  Input: {"name":"Duff"}
  Result: {"beer":{"name":"Duff"},"filled":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2015-02-23T07:00:17.485Z"},"id":"olLXh0F54E","kickedReports":[]}
I2015-02-23T07:00:17.438Z]false
I2015-02-23T07:00:17.523Z]Keg updated to Duff.
I2015-02-23T07:00:17.525Z]Sending notifications that keg is refilled to 'Duff'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally understand it. In `sendKegRefillNotification`, you're calling `query.find({...})`, then returning an object. That `find` is asynchronous, and you're doing nothing to wait for the result. I think you need to return the `find` function call, rather than an object you set within that method.

In other words, you're running along, leaving some async running code behind you.

Edit: I understand what you tried to do. It sort of makes sense. You defined a promise, and thought the caller would wait for the promise. The problem is, the promise is **defined** in an asynchronous block. It doesn't yet have any meaning at the moment the caller gets it.

Comment: Yes, I understand now. It was a mistake to try to create a promise and set it but rather I should chain the promises together. That fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Parse doesn't allow you to run a query from inside a callback from save(). When I moved "notify.sendKegRefillNotification(keg);" to outside of the callback, it worked.

```
var fillKeg = function(beerName) {
    var promise = new Parse.Promise();

    var keg = new Keg();
    keg.set("beerName", beerName)
    keg.set("kickedReports", []);
    keg.save(null, { useMasterKey: true }).then(function(keg) {
        console.log("Keg updated to " + beerName + ".");
        console.log("Send notifications.");
        promise.resolve(keg);
    },
    function(keg, error) {
        promise.reject(error);
    });

    notify.sendKegRefillNotification(keg); // Now this works

    return promise;
}
```

Can anyone shed some more light on why this worked?

Comment: That answer smells wrong to me. A limitation of that sort would be completely going against the Parse spirit. (I'm using queries in my own save callbacks, but the logic is a rare case, and I can't actually be positive it works.)